# Flutter line graph with lot of data

Tags: flutter, graph

I working on a flutter project and I am looking for a line graph that I can use to display for instance 29 000 data points. Something similar to stock market chat where you can select day view or 4h, a week etc.

The graphs that I reviewed recently they become very slow when I load more data.

Comment: Can you show us some code, please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.